# Angular 2 how to call a jQuery function from a external script from a component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Need to call an external/vendor function from a component. In index.html the call looks like:

```
function doSomething(id) {
  $.somethingSpace("doSomething",id);
}
```

Now I want to call $.somethingSpace("doSomething",id) from a component:

```
let $ = require('../../assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js');
let something = require('../../assets/jquery.Something.js');
...
doSomething(id : string) : void {
  $.somethingSpace("doSomething",id);
}
```

But get an error: $.somethingSpace is not a function. How to do it the right way? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [article](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/), you can use do this:

```
declare var $: any;
```

And you don't forget to inject jquery into index.html.